# Using IIF Statement with DateDiff, True Is Not Working

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
  (SELECT IIF([Date Retired/Left] = NULL, DateDiff("yyyy", [Date Employed],Now()),
DateDiff("yyyy",[Date Employed],[Date Retired/Left])) 
FROM [Employment History] 
WHERE [Employment History].EmployeeID = [Training History].EmployeeID) 
AS [Time Employed]
```

This is a subquery that returns the correct value if [Date Retired/Left] holds a date however when it does not hold a date i.e. has not left or retired I want to collect the length of employment to now. I've attempted to use the Now () command but cannot get it to work, receiving blanks in these fields.

Apologies if it is a simple error, I am a fresh novice trying SQL for the first time this week.

[Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ehEm.png)
[image: EmploymentLengths]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been forever since the last time I've worked with ms-access, but I think the problem is this part: `[Date Retired/Left] = NULL`.

In every database I know, you can't compare values to `NULL` - the result will always be either `false` or `unknown`. You need to change that to `[Date Retired/Left] IS NULL`.

So your sub query should be this:

```
(SELECT IIF([Date Retired/Left] IS NULL, 
             DateDiff("yyyy", [Date Employed], Now()),
             DateDiff("yyyy", [Date Employed], [Date Retired/Left])
            ) 
FROM [Employment History] 
WHERE [Employment History].EmployeeID = [Training History].EmployeeID) 
AS [Time Employed]
```

Comment: If I was a wizard, I would be on the beach in Hawaii right now... just a programmer... but glad to help :-)